# mmcli -m 0 saying modem not found, but I can connect

Tags: networking, modem, 4g

A above, my remote device is saying the modem cannot be found, BUT I am can log in over a 4g network. The command mmcli -m 0 was working before and then I locked my modem to 4g, now its saying; "error: couldn't find modem"

My question is, how can I have it display the mmcli -m 0 output again?

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and it was quite simple. The cpu is seeing the modem as 1 now instead of 0.

mmcli -m 1 will pull up my modem details now. I'm guessing on reboot it will revert to 0.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can also just use:

```
mmcli -m any
```

and `mmcli` will report on any modem it's detected. Note I'm not sure what it does if you have multiple modems - I've only ever had one.